# xpath on html source code

Tags: xpath

Hi i would like to extract all the amenities in the html file bellow that have tag `alt="Has amenity / Allowed"`,like for example TV,Internet ...
I did a following code :

```
var descriptionNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='amenities']//li//");
```

but it does not filter the `alt="...."` in the `<img>` ,it just shows all the text (amenities in my case).If i add in the `("//div[@id='amenities']//li//img")` it does not show anything.I also tried with contains but without result.

```
<div id="amenities" style="display:none" class="details_content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Smoking Allowed </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Pets Allowed </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>TV </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Cable TV </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Internet <a class="tooltip" title="Internet (wired or wireless)"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Wireless Internet <a class="tooltip" title="A wireless router that guests can access 24/7."><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Air Conditioning </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Heating </p>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Elevator in Building </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Handicap Accessible <a class="tooltip" title="The property is easily accessible.  Guests should communicate about individual needs."><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Pool <a class="tooltip" title="A private swimming pool"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Kitchen <a class="tooltip" title="Kitchen is available for guest use"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Parking Included </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Doorman </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Gym <a class="tooltip" title="Guests have free access to a gym"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Hot Tub </p>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Indoor Fireplace </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Buzzer/Wireless Intercom </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Breakfast <a class="tooltip" title="Breakfast is provided."><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Family/Kid Friendly <a class="tooltip" title="The property is suitable for hosting families with children."><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a1.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/no_amenity-7229ab239bb2e3d81da7aa5034c265d4.png" title="Doesn't have amenity / Not allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Suitable for Events <a class="tooltip" title="The property can accommodate a gathering of 25 or more attendees."><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Washer <a class="tooltip" title="Paid or Free, in building"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                          <img alt="Has amenity / Allowed" class="amenity-icon" height="17" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/page3/v3/has_amenity-3f3ba6d898588b24e37211888d98713f.png" title="Has amenity / Allowed" width="17" />
                        <p>Dryer <a class="tooltip" title="Paid or Free, in building"><img alt="Questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3" src="//a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/icons/questionmark_hover-aaf1c7ee20bcff9b9ed6e8e5ef1af8e3.png" style="width:12px; height:12px;" /></a></p>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not filtering by `alt` attribute because you haven't told it to. You need to apply a predicate, like you currently are for `id`:

```
//div[@id='amenities']//li[img/@alt='Has amenity / Allowed']
```

That selects only those `li` tags whose inner image has the required `alt` attribute.

Comment: Thanks,but i see i have another problem now,with the SelectSingleNode i will choose the first amenities that the the code finds it.If i use SelectNodes then what can i do to make a array of strings with the list of amenities that have the attribute alt='Has amenity / allowed'.

Comment: You've sort of answered your own question there - surely `SelectNodes()` returns all matches, presumably as an array, which is what you need - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.